# How to establish relationships using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I was hoping that someone could help me correctly setup the relationships in Sequelize. I believe I have the models correctly setup, but I am not sure as I have never used the api before, and the documentation is confusing. I have attached a picture of what I think the tables should look like, and below are some code snippets of what I think should happen but I can't tell.

Any pointers on if my DB design is accurate or not, and whether or not my sequelize associations (hasMany, belongsTo, etc) are correct would be super helpful!

Users Model

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  //Define the user table, and its columns, data types, attributes
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    user_id: {...},
    user_name: {...}
   },    
   {
     //Define the constraints, such as foreign key
     classMethods:{
        associate: function(models) {
            User.belongsToMany(models.Group);
            User.hasMany(models.Old_Password);
        }
     }
   }); 

  return User;
};
```

Roles Model

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){

  var Role = sequelize.define('Role',{
    role_id: {...},
    role_name:{...}
   },
   {
   //Define the constraints, such as foreign key
     classMethods:{
        associate: function(models){
            Role.belongsTo(models.User);
        }
     }
  }); 

  return Role;
};
```

Groups Model

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){

  var Group = sequelize.define('group', {
    group_id: {...},
    group_name: {...},                
   });

  return Group;
};
```

Password Model

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){

  //Define the table, and its columns, data types, attributes
  var Old_Password = sequelize.define('Old_Password', {
    old_password_id: {...},
    old_password_value: {...}
   },    
  {
  //Define the constraints, such as foreign key
    classMethods:{
        associate: function(models){
            Old_Password.hasOne(models.User);
        }
    }
  }); 

  return Old_Password;
};
```

[Sample Table Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyxzf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database design is accurate. However, you need to define the relationship between `User` and `Group`. It's a *many-to-many* relationship so you'll need to add another constraint to the `User` model:

```
classMethods:{
  associate: function(models){
    User.belongsToMany(models.Group, {
      // Define the join table
      through: 'user_group',
      // Define the foreign key
      foreignKey: 'group_id'
    });
    models.Group.belongsToMany(User, {
      through: 'user_group',
      foreignKey: 'user_id'
    });
    User.hasMany(models.Old_Password);
  }
}
```